# Chinese Striped-neck turtle above water

Tags: turtles

My brother recently bought a Chinese Striped-neck turtle, and he wants to know for how long can it be out of water.
Can you guys help me out?
Thanks in forward,
Roberto

Comment: Most turtles could get outside the water for long time as long as they (their skin) do not dry out. But one should.know the most turtles could not or like not to eat outside the water.